# acro's link-only-first option makes the (first) short appearance of an acronym wrongly linked to the last page of the document

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, acro

The `acro`'s documentation tells us:

> When `acro` is used together with the package `hyperref` [ORT21] then you can make use of the following option:
>
> `make-links = true|false`
> If this is activated then every short or alternative appearance of an acronym will be linked to its description in the list of acronyms.

And that is indeed the case in the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\acsetup{
  make-links = true,
  % link-only-first = true
}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = CD ,
  long = compact disc
}

\begin{document}
\ac{cd}
\newpage
\printacronyms
\newpage
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Next, the documentation tells us:

> `link-only-first = true|false`
>
> If this is activated in addition to `make-links` then only the first short or alternative appearance of an acronym will be linked to its description in the list of acronyms.

But, as soon as the `link-only-first` option is uncommented in the example above, the (first) short appearance of the acronym is linked:

- to the *last page* of the document,
- *not* to its description in the list of acronyms.

Interestingly enough, the `.aux` files are the same in both cases.

Do you understand what's going on and how to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is imho a bug in acro. It uses the same code inside the \printacronym to set the targets, and with the link-only-first boolean set to true the target is suppressed there too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\acsetup{
  make-links = true,
  link-only-first = true
}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = CD ,
  long = compact disc
}


\begin{document}
\ac{cd}
\newpage
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_set_false:N\l__acro_link_only_first_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff
\printacronyms
\newpage
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `acro`'s author attention [drawn](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/255).